# NULL data stored by overloaded istream

Tags: c++, loops, null, overloading, istream

This is part of my polynomial.cpp to get terms by overloading istream

```
void Newterm(float coef, int deg) {
        if (terms == capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            Term* tmp = new Term[capacity];
            copy(termArray, termArray + terms, tmp);
            termArray = tmp;
            delete[] tmp;
        }
        termArray[terms].degree = deg;
        termArray[terms++].coef = coef; 
    }
friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Polynomial& pl) {
        cout << "number of terms : ";
        int t; is >> t;
        cout << endl;   
    float coeff;
    int degree;
        for (int i = 0; i < t;i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << "'s term: ";
      is >> coeff >> degree;
            pl.Newterm(coeff, degree);  
        }
        return is;
    };
```

[image: this is input and output but the printed result(not posted printfunc) says NULL stored in term]

---

of course, i tried to figure out whaaat made this result..
tried:

1. removing 'for' loop

   - this actually worked.. but it only works when terms=1
2. firstly creating term and input data

   - `Newterm(0,0);`
     `is>>pl.termArray[i].coef>>pl.termArray[i].degree;`
   - it couldn't fix anything...

---

so i think it has to do with loops..
but whyyyy?

Comment: In `Newterm`, you are `delete[]` ing the resized buffer just after reallocation.

Comment: I think you don't reallocate at the right time. terms == capacity looks suspicious. Usually entries in an array go from 0 to (capacity-1). So I expect more of a test if(terms < capacity) { add terms } else { reallocate }. But why not just use a std::vector<Term> and all the memory managment will be done for you.

Comment: @prapin ohhhh thanks!!

Comment: i just solved this one simply `delete[] termArray;` and remainig `tmp`

Comment: @cuBerry Is the goal of your program to solve Polynomials, or to maintain a dynamic array?  If it's solve Polynomials, then use `std::vector`.  Why have buggy home-made dynamic array code slow you down from reaching this goal?  You still have to write the code to solve (or whatever you want to do) with the Polynomial, so why put an artificial road-block in the way on purpose?

Comment: `termArray = tmp;`  resulted problem, because `tmp` is referred by `termArray`? is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Using std::vector instead of doing your own memory managment
(why reinvent the wheel if there is a tested solution in the standard library)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Term final
{
    Term() = default;
    ~Term() = default;

    Term(int d, double c) :
        degree{ d },
        coef{ c }
    {
    }

    int degree{ 0 };
    double coef{ 1.0 };
};

class Polynomial final
{
public:
    Polynomial() = default;
    ~Polynomial() = default;

    explicit Polynomial(const std::initializer_list<Term> terms) :
        m_terms{ terms }
    {
    }

    void add(const Term& term)
    {
        m_terms.push_back(term);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Term> m_terms;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Polynomial& polynomial)
{
    std::size_t n{ 0 }; // indices are not ints the can't be < 0
    is >> n;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        Term term{};
        is >> term.coef;
        is >> term.degree;
        polynomial.add(term);
    }

    return is;
}


int main()
{
    // to show you that std::vector can handle all the memory managment for you
    // constructor with an initializer list that adds 3 terms
    // that's also why the Term has a constructor, it is to make it work with
    // initializer list
    Polynomial p{ { 1,2.0 }, { 2,4.0 }, { 1,-1.0 } };
}
```